# lauterbach scripting: checking if program stops at breakpoint

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I have to check by way of a script if a program stops at a breakpoint:
example:

break.set func1 /Program

Go

IF (program stops at breakpoint)
(
do smth
)

I am new to this language and I cannot seem to find relevant information on google.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know whether the program stops at the program you need to wait a certain (defined by you) amount of time and then check the run-state of the processor, and if stopped then check whether the PC is at your symbol.

```
; set breakpoint
Break.Set func1 /Program

; start processor
Go

; wait until processor stopped or 5 seconds elasped
WAIT !STATE.RUN() 5.0s

IF STATE.RUN()
(
    PRINT %ERROR "Processor still running!"
    ENDDO
)

; check PC
IF R(PC)!=sYmbol.BEGIN(func1)
(
    PRINT %ERROR "Processor stopped but wrong PC!"
    ENDDO
)

PRINT "Test passed!"

ENDDO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actual goal is to execute a script when a breakpoint gets hit, I recommend to used the option `/CMD` of the `Break.Set`.
E.g.:

```
Break.Set  func1 /Program /CMD "DO smth.cmm"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is will actually help me in my future scripts